# JSON string into Object Model using Newtonsoft library

Tags: json

I have the following JSON string :

```
{
  "screen": {
    "@id": "12345",
    "@name": "My Screening Questionnaire",
    "@successful": "True",
    "question": [
      {
        "@id": "123",
        "@type": "MultipleChoiceOneAnswer",
        "@text": "What is your current work status?",
        "answer": [
          {
            "@id": "1",
            "@selected": "True",
            "#text": "Australian citizen"
          },
          {
            "@id": "2",
            "#text": "NZ citizen"
          },
          {
            "@id": "3",
            "#text": "Australian permanent resident"
          },
          {
            "@id": "4",
            "#text": "NZ permanent resident"
          },
          {
            "@id": "5",
            "#text": "Australian work visa"
          },
          {
            "@id": "6",
            "#text": "NZ work visa"
          },
          {
            "@id": "7",
            "#text": "Holiday working visa"
          },
          {
            "@id": "8",
            "#text": "Other"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@id": "124",
        "@type": "MultipleChoiceOneAnswer",
        "@text": "When are you available to begin employment?",
        "answer": [
          {
            "@id": "1",
            "@selected": "True",
            "#text": "Now"
          },
          {
            "@id": "2",
            "#text": "2 weeks"
          },
          {
            "@id": "3",
            "#text": "1 month"
          },
          {
            "@id": "4",
            "#text": "1 –2 months"
          },
          {
            "@id": "5",
            "#text": "3 or more months"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@id": "125",
        "@type": "Text",
        "@text": "Why do you consider yourself to be a suitable candidate for this position?",
        "answer": {
          "@id": "1",
          "@selected": "True",
          "#text": "I’m great"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to convert it into an Object model using Newtonsoft

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject:T:(JsonStringText)

What will be the structure of the object Model ?

Thanks.

You can refer to the JSON model returned here :

http://developer.seek.com.au/docs/partner-api/api-methods/applicationexport/get-screen

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the object returned from `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject:T:(JsonStringText)`?

Comment: I get an object with no structure. When you apply .ToString() on it you get back the JSON string

Comment: I will just get it as JObject and loop the object and construct the model I want.